# Haskellで謎のエラー: parse error on input '|'

Tags: haskell

Haskellで以下のようなコード(ほぼhttps://wiki.haskell.org/99_questionsの11と10の丸写し)を書いたところ、1行目で
`error: parse error on input '|'`
と言われてしまいました。
どなたか解決策をご教授ください

```
ListItem a = Single a | Multiple Int a
    deriving (Show)

enc :: Eq a => [a] -> [(Int, a)]
enc [] = []
enc li@(x:xs) = ((length $ filter (==x) li),x):(enc $ filter (/=x) xs)

encodeModified :: Eq a => [a] -> [ListItem a]
encodeModified = map encodeHelper . enc
  where
    encodeHelper (1,x) = Single x
    encodeHelper (n,x) = Multiple n x

    main = do
      print $ encodeModified "aaaaafheeeeeiiiiii"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

先頭の`data`が欠けているためでは？

```
data ListItem a = Single a | Multiple Int a
    deriving (Show)
```

Comment: ghci で `=` のところで parse error が出るのは `a=3` で怒られるのと同じで，今回とは別の問題だと思います．（ちなみに， `ghc 8.0` からは `a=3` を[解釈してくれるようになりました](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7253)．）

Comment: 写しミスというアホミスでした...

Comment: 確かにghciで試すというのは安易すぎました。